# How does one dynamically build a treelist using pure Javascript or a library like underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, treelist

I'm having trouble getting the output from the following json

```
`[
 {theLevel:1,displayName: "John Doe1", index:1, parIndex:null },
 {theLevel:1,displayName: "John Doe2", index:2, parIndex:null },
 {theLevel:2,displayName: "John Doe3", index:3, parIndex:1 },
 {theLevel:2,displayName: "John Doe4", index:4, parIndex:1 },
 {theLevel:3,displayName: "John Doe5", index:5, parIndex:2 },
 {theLevel:3,displayName: "John Doe6", index:6, parIndex:2 },
]`
```

My expected output is as follows:

```
  [
      {text:"John Doe1", items:[{text:"John Doe3"},{text:"John Doe4"} ]},
      {text: "John Doe2, items:[{text:"John Doe5"},{text:"John Doe6"}]} ]
```

Comment: And what JavaScript are you using in order to obtain your expected output?

Comment: I tried a so many things, can't get anything to work.

Comment: My apologies, I was suggesting that you need to show us some of your attempts, and explain where they went wrong; what did they do that they shouldn't, what didn't they do that they should? As it is, we have some input, your desired output and nothing else, which feels like you're just asking us to solve your problem without explaining what your problem is.

Comment: My attempts probably wont add any value, as I didn't even get close. I'll keep trying thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user is asking to get his work done without showing any effort from his side

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution which does a few iterations of the whole data to produce a tree. Some of these iterations can be combined to improve performance but here I've left them as they are so that it's clearer what's going on:

1. Add a children property to each person

   ```
   _.each(data, function(person){
       _.extend(person, {children: []});
   });
   ```
2. Create a hash of the data with the index of the person as the key and the person as the value

   ```
   var people = _.reduce(data, function(memo, person){
       memo[person.index] = person
       return memo;
   }, {} );
   ```

   The people object will look like so:

   ```
   {
      1: {theLevel:1,displayName: "John Doe1", index:1, parIndex:null },
      2: {theLevel:1,displayName: "John Doe2", index:2, parIndex:null },
      3: {theLevel:2,displayName: "John Doe3", index:3, parIndex:1 }
      etc.
   }
   ```
3. Add each child to the children of it's parent:

   ```
   _.each(data, function(person){
       if( !_.isNull(person.parIndex)) people[person.parIndex].children.push(person);
   });
   ```

   This will leave you with a tree.
4. You can then transform this tree into whatever you like. This snippet will produce the output in the question:

   ```
   function isParent (person) {
       return !_.isEmpty(person.children);
   }

   var parents = _.filter(people, isParent);

   var result = _.map(parents, function(person){
       return {
           text: person.displayName,
           items: _.map(person.children, function(child){
               return { text: child.displayName };
           })
       };
   ```

Comment: Worked fine, I think that I only need the items array if there actually are children but I should be able to handle that. Thanks.

Comment: Have added a filter to extract just the parents.

Comment: I'll have to give that a shot, this will work with any number of levels ? Because the first level is the top level then I keeps going. I could have the items array nested several times.

Comment: Yes, step 3 builds a tree by iterating over all the data and adding each person to their parent's children collection.

Comment: the last transformation seems to be flatting the nesting to only two levels. var result = _.map(parents, function(person){
    return {
        text: person.displayName,
        items: _.map(person.children, function(child){
            return { text: child.displayName };
        })
    };

Answer (score 0):

I did the following which seems to work with one minor issue. I'm getting an empty items array for some of the children. I would rather there be nothing if the items's array is empty.

1. Add children and text property

   ```
   = _.each(results.data, function (entity) {
             _.extend(entity, { text: entity.displayName });
             _.extend(entity, { items: [] });
      });
   ```
2. Create hash as before

   ```
     = _.reduce(results.data, function (memo, entities) {
                       memo[entities.entIndex] = entities;
                       return memo;
                   }, {});
   ```
3. Add each child to parent as before

   ```
   = _.each(results.data, function (entity) {
       if (!_.isNull(entity.parEntIndex)) ent[entity.parEntIndex].items.push(entity);
                   });
   ```

   4.

   ```
   function isParent (entity) {
                       return !_.isEmpty(entity.items) && entity.theLev == 1;
                   }

                   var test = _.filter(combine, isParent);

                   var result = _.map(test, function (currentObject) {
                       return _.pick(currentObject,'text','items');
                   });
   ```